# How to include external js file in YII views?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

i am new to YII framework, and currently using YII 2.0 !
Could anyone help me to include external js file in view file ? I tried the below code.

Js file is in `" frontend/web/themes/js/new.js "`

view file is in `"frontend/views/dash/index.php"`

In view :

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/new.js',['depends' => [yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

In Assests/Appasset.php I included

```
public $js = [
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js',
      'themes/js/bootstrap.min.js',
      'themes/js/new.js'  
    ];
```

but still, unable to run js functions in view. Pls Help.

Comment: Can you check in the page source if the JS files are found? How/when are you trying to use the JS functions?

Comment: Did you define the assest in your view file? Like: Appasset::register($this) or is it included in main layout file? Please specify.

Comment: Try adding `@app` to your function, like this:

    $this->registerJsFile('@app/js/new.js',['depends' => [yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);